# Connect to a MySQL database with Lua

Tags: mysql, lua

I am very new to Lua and I am going to try to connect to a MySQL server.
This will be used in a game (modded version of Minecraft/ComputerCraft) to get information from a MySQL database.

Is this possible and how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if its works but, maybe you can try LUASQL
http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/index.html#overview

Comment: I'll try that later today

Comment: There also luadbi(https://code.google.com/p/luadbi). I do not use it but from doc it support prepared/parametrized query. And my library ODBC (https://github.com/moteus/lua-odbc)